# Showing PDF in VC# 2k8

Tags: c#, pdf, controls, licensing

I'm looking for a solution to display a PDF in C#. I found the AxAcroPDFLib Control, that works very fine and is sufficient.

But other people can't start my program, because they get an exception "AxInterop.AcroPDFLib" not found. But they have the latest Adobe PDF Reader installed. OS is Windows 7!

How can I fix that problem? (maybe add a acrobat dll to the working directory?)
What's about the licence to use that?

Are there other possibilites/libraries/controls to show a PDF? Maybe under LGPL licence?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you sent your interop assembly with your original program?

Comment: Oh I see that there are DLLs created in my bin directory I didn't committed. Sorry!

But what's about its licence? I want to sell my Program...

Answer (score 2):

This is a little out there, but you could try using the WebBrowser control and point it to a HTML page that has  tag pointing to your file.

Also see http://www.pdftron.com/. It is a commercial product, they have a custom pdf viewer as one of their samples.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

[Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/index.html) is a small, light weight and free PDF viewer (not a control). You could make your PDF viewable by launching it in Sumatra PDF. I don't think it will allow you to embed a viewer in a form as a control however.

Answer (score 0):

What about http://live.gnome.org/PdfMod? They have a Windows port. And I believe using it you can go without Adobe Reader.